# Choose between intermediary banks?

Tags: international-transfer, swift

I'm trying to get the money from my client in the USA but transfers from Chase do not seem to pass compliance at NY Mellon (the intermediary bank).

My UAE bank has 4 correspondent banks for USD transfers (Citi NY, NY Mellon, Standard Chartered NY and HSBC NY). Is it possible to choose the intermediary bank when sending a USD wire from Chase?

The financial analyst from the client side is stating that the intermediary bank is determined by the destination bank and can not be chosen by them.

Thanks

Comment: do not seem to pass compliance at NY Mellon - why is that? Maybe address the root cause instead of trying to bypass? Usually these checks would be similar in all the banks.

Comment: @littleadv the client company name matches the name of a Russian company sanctioned by the US in November. NY Mellon was asking them about their ties to that specific similarly named company, got the response but still did not let the payment through.

Comment: What makes you think a different bank won't do the same thing? Generally, trying to circumvent sanctions in the US can lead to more troubles. Americans don't like these games. They'd rather you not doing business with them at all than mistakenly allow you through when they shouldn't have.

Comment: @littleadv US company is called X (a common word), Russian company that has no ties to the US company called itself X. There are no sanctions imposed against the US company. Therefore there can be no sanctions circumvention.

Comment: Your statement about different banks having similar compliance is not correct. Sending USD to officially non-sanctioned Belarussian banks used to work through some banks and not through others.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say. What I'm trying to say is that I, as an American, knowing that X is sanctioned, may not want to bother myself with trying to figure out how many Xs there are and which one specifically I'm dealing with. They don't *have to* provide services to you. For banks it is all about risk management. You're a risk.

Comment: @littleadv well, this is why I am trying to have them try send the payment through a different intermediary, hence the question :)